# How to handle POST requests with >5MB of JSON data from one nodejs API endpoint to another?

Tags: json, node.js, http, post

I have to send a lot of data from one API endpoint to another - could be 5MB or even up to 10MB.
Should I split this up into smaller chunks?
Or should I use some kind of JSON streaming technique?

Any insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

nodejs netsockets are already streams.  They will block if you put too much in them until the other end reads it.

Assume by API endpoint you are talking http (or https or http2) which are all built on top of netsockets.

Do `response.write` of smallish chunks (I think the buffer size defaults to 16KB, so well under that) until a `false` return (meaning you've filled up) and listen for the `'drain'` event for it to be free again and you can continue to write. Call `response.end` when you are finished

Comment: or should I think about a different solution than `http`?

Comment: the benefit of `http` is it goes through firewalls. Anything else, and you might need special configuration somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two things that might work for you, and they both involve [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).  You should break up the string manually into 16k chunks (or use something like chunking-streams (https://github.com/Olegas/node-chunking-streams/tree/master/lib) to do it for you)

Now for the two methods:

- Use a [pull-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/pull-stream), which can sit on top of regular node.js streams via stream-to-pull-stream (https://github.com/dominictarr/stream-to-pull-stream). It will prevent the receiving side from reading any more (like a kafka topic) until it needs more.
- Use [mux-demux](https://github.com/dominictarr/mux-demux).  It has a really neat built in 'pause' mechanism, where if the buffer on the receiving side is full, it will 'tell' the sending side to stop sending more data until the buffer has more space.

Then, you just append all the data from the stream until the stream sends the 'end' event, meaning no more data is available.